# Search tool to extract and manipulate C-functions from a header file

Tags: c, parsing, header, c-preprocessor, function-prototypes

my problem seems very simple…

PROBLEM: I have a header file with many prototypes… (like the example)

```
...
// some docu...
MQ_EXTERN enum MqErrorE
MQ_DECL MqSlaveWorker (
  struct MqS * const    ctx,
  MQ_NUM const          id,
  MQ_CST                factory,
  struct MqBufferLS **  argsP
);
...
```

ASKING FOR: a TOOL to generate a second header-file with "wrapped" definitions of the original header-file …

```
....
#define MqSlaveWorkerE(ctx,id,factory,argsP) \
  MqErrorCheck(MqSlaveWorker(ctx,id,factory,argsP))
....
```

The *trigger* is the *return-type* **enum MqErrorE** ...
all prototypes with *return-type* **enum MqErrorE** should get a c-preprocessor-wrapper

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "...NOW I want a TOOL to generate a code-wrapper like…"
-> I just search for a tool to do the job from above…

Comment: There isn't a tool for your issue. So, if you want it, you should to write it. There are many instruments which can help you to write this tool, such like: sed, awk, perl etc.

Comment: @freestyle: You aren't going to get a text-based string processor to reliably parse C header files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a [Program Transformation System (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

These are tools that read source code, build internal representations of your program, and allow you to code source-to-source transformations that operate on th internal representations for efficiency.  When you are done applying transformation, the tool converts the internal representation back into text and spits out the transformed source code, even with comments preserved.

Unless your header files are trivial, you'll need one that actually has a full C parser and can accurately capture your source code.   Otherwise it won't be able to read your files and now you're nowhere. Even that isn't enough; it has to preserve preprocessor declarations so they can be manipulated as opposed to vanishing during preprocessing.  There's lots more to a front end; you typically want name resolution and various flow analyzers.

There aren't a lot of production-capable PTSes around.   Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=StackOverflow) is the only one I know (and I've been doing this for a very long time) that has a full [C Front End](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html?Home=CTools?site=StackOverflow), that can preserve preprocessor commands.

The core of your task is summarized in this DMS rewrite rule:

```
rule generate-wrapper(extern: macro_name, decl: macro_name, function_name: IDENTIFIER, a: arguments):
    prototype_declaration)->preprocessor_declaration =
    " \extern enum MqErrorE \decl \function_name ( \a ) " ->
    "#define \generate_derived_macro_name\(\function_name\) (\extract_parameter_name\(\a\) ) \\
       \generate_derived_checker_name\(\function_name\)( (\extract_parameter_name\(\a\) )"
```

where generate_derived_macro name, generate_derived_checker_name and extract_parameter_name_list are custom functions.  generated_derived_macro name based on your example takes its argument and glues an "E" to it.  extract paramter name is more interesing; it has to take the interal (AST) for the parameters list, pick out the parameter names, and construct an argument list from those names.   DMS provides the machinery to help you code this.

And there's more work to do: you actually want to build your error checking functions (which this rewrite does) and then shuffle them to an internal form AST that represents a seperate header file.   This takes additional custom code, but DMS keeps track of multiple representations easily and can move trees around easily.

If you have 50 of these declarations, frankly you'll do better to bite the bullet and just do it by hand.  If you have thousands, DMS will probably save  you a lot of time.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

after ~3h programming… the solution is a (tcl) script using a lot of
**regexp** to do the following steps…

a. filter out all *not* wanted code

b. transform the wanted code into use able pieces

c. format the pieces into wanted **#define...** preprocessor code

STEP 1. make the transformation

```
> ./sbin/parse_c_header.tcl
1. 221725 chars after read from 'msgque.h'
2. 221581 chars after '…\n'
2. 107796 chars after '//…$'
3. 57823 chars after '/*…*/'
4. 49701 chars after '{…}'
5. 48303 chars after '{…}'
6. 47839 chars after 'struct…XX…;'
7. 47653 chars after 'enum…XX…;'
8. 40458 chars after '#…'
9. 37707 chars after '\n'
10. 35346 chars after 'typedef…'
11. 35123 chars after 'struct…;'
12. 35053 chars after 'union…;'
13. 32820 chars after '__attribute__…;'
14. 32802 chars after 's+'
15. 32338 chars after '*'
16. 32332 chars after '[]'
17. 24076 chars after '(…,'
18. 20499 chars after ',…)'
19. 20499 chars after ',…,'
20. 17935 chars after '(…)'
21. 17979 chars after '__VA_ARGS__'
22. 17946 chars after 'XX;'
23. 17861 chars after ';'
24. 17861 chars after '…\n'
25. 17500 chars after ';\n'
write: msgqueE.h
```

STEP 2. write the results

```
//
//   this file was automatically created by 'sbin/parse_c_header.tcl'
//
//     : do NOT modify it
//
//   this file contains error-protected api-calls of libmsgque
//
//     : error-protected mean that all api-calls who return an 'enum MqErrorE'
//     : get a 'MqErrorCheck' wrapper. This wrapper check for the return code
//     : 'MQ_ERROR' and jump on error to a label called 'error:' to do proper
//     : error handing.
//
//   example: the following line of code..
//
//      > MqErrorCheck ( MqReadU (ctx, &buf));
//
//   can be rewritten with:
//
//      > #include "msgqueE.h"
//      > ...
//      > MqReadUE (ctx, &buf);
//
//
#define        MqConfigSetIoUdsFileE (ctx,file)          MqErrorCheck(MqConfigSetIoUdsFile(ctx,file))
#define            MqConfigSetIoTcpE (myhost,myport)     MqErrorCheck(MqConfigSetIoTcp(myhost,myport))
#define     MqConfigSetIoPipeSocketE (ctx,hdl)           MqErrorCheck(MqConfigSetIoPipeSocket(ctx,hdl))
#define           MqConfigSetDaemonE (ctx,pidfile)       MqErrorCheck(MqConfigSetDaemon(ctx,pidfile))
#define      MqFactoryDefaultCreateE (item,contextP)     MqErrorCheck(MqFactoryDefaultCreate(item,contextP))
#define             MqFactoryCtxSetE (ctx,item)          MqErrorCheck(MqFactoryCtxSet(ctx,item))
#define        MqFactoryCtxIdentSetE (ctx,ident)         MqErrorCheck(MqFactoryCtxIdentSet(ctx,ident))
#define MqCheckForLeftOverArgumentsE (ctx,argvP)         MqErrorCheck(MqCheckForLeftOverArguments(ctx,argvP))
#define               MqStorageOpenE (ctx,storageFile)   MqErrorCheck(MqStorageOpen(ctx,storageFile))
#define              MqStorageCloseE (ctx)               MqErrorCheck(MqStorageClose(ctx))
#define             MqStorageInsertE (ctx,transLIdP)     MqErrorCheck(MqStorageInsert(ctx,transLIdP))
#define             MqStorageSelectE (ctx,transLIdP)     MqErrorCheck(MqStorageSelect(ctx,transLIdP))
#define             MqStorageDeleteE (ctx,transLId)      MqErrorCheck(MqStorageDelete(ctx,transLId))
#define              MqStorageCountE (ctx,countP)        MqErrorCheck(MqStorageCount(ctx,countP))
#define                MqLinkCreateE (ctx,args)          MqErrorCheck(MqLinkCreate(ctx,args))
#define               MqLinkConnectE (ctx)               MqErrorCheck(MqLinkConnect(ctx))
#define           MqLinkCreateChildE (parent,args)       MqErrorCheck(MqLinkCreateChild(parent,args))
#define           MqLinkCreateRouteE (id,argvP)          MqErrorCheck(MqLinkCreateRoute(id,argvP))
#define               MqLinkDefaultE (ctx,args)          MqErrorCheck(MqLinkDefault(ctx,args))
#define               MqLinkGetPathE (ctx,pathP)         MqErrorCheck(MqLinkGetPath(ctx,pathP))
#define               MqLinkGetTreeE (ctx,tree)          MqErrorCheck(MqLinkGetTree(ctx,tree))
...
```